# Get instagram photo url from android after intent

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, instagram-api

I want to post an image to instagram from android, I've seen that this is only possible using the android intent system with the instagram call.

I need to retrieve the url of the posted image after the intent, is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you authenticate the user through the instagram auth flow within your app you may know the username and issue a api call to [get_user_media_recent](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) to have the latest pic posted by the user.

Unfortunately you are not able to use the username directly but you've to reverse the userid from the username. [use this](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search)

Both api calls doesn't actually need to be authenticated you might use the client_id= paramether instead of the access_token. But you'll still need to know the username or the userid.

**Otherwise**, since you might want to startActivityForResult and inspect the returning Intent data. But be aware that since this is not a public api you are going to be strictly depending to instagram app and their mods on the code.